# Rename image file before uploading to server

Tags: php

I'm stuck in this bit of code that uploads multiple images to the server, basically I want to rename the images before uploading to the server to prevent duplicates. Currently this code works perfectly fine but the images filename remains the same, How can I rename the image file that has been Uploaded ?

```
                  $file_dir  = "../files/images/";

              /* Check if folder not exists, then create it */
              if (!file_exists($file_dir)) {
                mkdir($file_dir, 0777, true);
              }

              if (isset($_POST["Input"])) {

                /* conversi multi array */
                function diverse_array($array) { 
                  $result = []; 
                  foreach($array as $key1 => $value1) 
                    foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2) 
                      $result[$key2][$key1] = $value2; 

                  return $result; 
                }

                $file_multi  = diverse_array($_FILES['upload']);

                for ($y = 0; $y < 7; $y++) {    
                  $image[$y] = '';
                }

                /* loop multi file */           
                for ($x = 0; $x < count($file_multi); $x++) {

                  /* loop array file $_FILES */                 
                  foreach ($file_multi[$x] as $key => $value) {

                    $file_name   = $file_multi[$x]['name'];
                    $file_size   = $file_multi[$x]['size'];
                    $file_tmp    = $file_multi[$x]['tmp_name'];



                    $file_target = $file_dir . $file_name;

                    $errors = array();  

                    /* Check current file formats with file secure */
                    $file_secure  = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp');                  
                    $file_current = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); /* (end(explode('.', $file_name) */

                    if (in_array($file_current, $file_secure) === false) {
                      $errors[] = "Sorry, <strong>{$file_current}</strong> extension not allowed";      
                    }

                  }

                  /* Check if Errors exist, then not upload. Or if Errors NOT exist, then try upload */
                  if (!empty($errors)) {                            

                    /* display error */                 
                    foreach ($errors as $keyError => $valueError) {
                      echo "$keyError = $valueError <br />";
                    }                           

                  } else {

                    if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_target)) {

                      $image[$x] = $file_target;

                      echo "<strong>{$file_name}</strong> has been uploaded." . "<br />";

                    } else {

                      echo "Sorry, there was an something wrong in <b>move_uploaded</b>.";

                    }

                  }                     

                }                   

                /* Check for error */
                if (!empty($errors)) {                          

                  /* Check errors and display them */                   
                  foreach ($errors as $keyError => $valueError) {
                    echo "$keyError = $valueError <br />";
                  }                     

                /* if everything is ok, try to upload file */
                } else {

                  /* Insert Form Data into Database */
```

Comment: Look at manual for `move_uploaded_file` function. Parameter 2 is the name you are saving it as so instead of `$file_multi[$x]['name']` use the name you want.. or possibly hash it with the time and that likely will be unique

Comment: One way to go about it is using the current time(hour minute sec) to concatenate with the file name.

Comment: @user3783243 You're right.  I was wrong.  I forgot she wanted to rename it.

Comment: @user3783243 If I did not know the user id I use` $id = str_replace('.','',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);` and create a folder with their id.  I did not care if they over wrote it.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to create a folder and dump the images there, actually I'm passing variable ID and I guess I could create an ID folder put I dont  know how to.

Comment: If you want to create a new folder, use `mkdir`.